# class member function pointer... is my code right?

Tags: c++

I had see ton of code about class pointer function member with weird and strange klingon code for my cpp skill...

I find this sooo easy solution...
but I'm not sure to do the right thing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class CLP{
    public:
        typedef void(CLP::*event)();
        struct Param {
            string trigger;
            event ev;
        };
        vector<Param>params;

        void parse(string s){
            for(const auto p:params){ // why use const ?
                if (p.trigger==s){
                    (this->*p.ev)(); // here Im not sure for "this" 
                }
            }
        }
};

class MyClp : public CLP{
    public:
        MyClp(){
            params={
                {"-o",(event)&MyClp::ocall},
                {"-p",(event)&MyClp::pcall}
            };
        }
        void ocall(){
            cout << "MyClp::ocall" << endl;
        }
        void pcall(){
            cout << "MyClp::pcall" << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    MyClp myclp;
    myclp.parse("-o");
    myclp.parse("-p");
}
```

output

```
MyClp::ocall
MyClp::pcall
```

thankx

Comment: What *problem are you trying to solve* by doing this?

Comment: Use const to show that you don't want to modify. I would change to: `auto const& p:params` (add & to make a reference) otherwise each member of the vector is copied into `p`.

Comment: You can take your code for a review here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: (1) To avoid the potential undefined behavior, You should have a single class. (2) Also prefer `using` to typedef for aliases (easier to read and more more modern). (3) Never use C style cast in C++. Casting should rerely be need in properly designed code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel
CLP is a command line parser "helper" lib.

Comment: @MartinYork oook thankx...

Comment: @Phil1970 (1) this code is an extract... CLP is a (futur) lib
(2) ok... let's use "using" now... 
(3) u mean "dynamic_cast" etc ? can u show me how use it in my code ?